# What's diffrence in jQuery ajax dataType="json" vs JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Is there any real diffrence between using dataType='json' and parse response by JSON.parse(response) in jQuery Ajax?

```
$.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            block : lang,
        },
    }).done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        output = response;
    });
```

**VS**

```
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            block : lang,
        },
    }).done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        output = JSON.parse(response);
    });
```

Comment: No. `dataType: 'json'` just tells jQuery that it should automatically parse the response.

Comment: If your server/service may not respond with JSON then you can set `dataType:"text"` and *inspect* the response first.  Calling JSON.parse without checking it's json when you know it might not be will give an error in those scenarios, as would dataType:json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataType: 'json'`:

- Sets the `Accept` request header to tell the server that JSON is the desired response format
- Attempts to parse the response as JSON regardless of what the server's `Content-Type` response header says the format is. (jQuery's default behaviour is to use the `Content-Type` to determine the correct parser).

`JSON.parse`:

- Attempts to parse the response data as a string of JSON regardless of what it actually is (if the server responds with correctly labelled JSON, this will error since it will have already been parsed by jQuery).